# What is the BigO of Collections.sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, big-o

I am using the collections.sort on two lists to alphabetize them. 
I have it inside a function and I am trying to determine its BigO

So i was wondering the BigO for Collections.sort(list)

```
    List list1 = new LinkedList();
    List list2 = new LinkedList();


    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
        list1.add(x.charAt(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++){
        list2.add(y.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(list1);
    Collections.sort(list1);
    System.out.println(list1);

    System.out.println(list2);
    Collections.sort(list2);
```

What would be the BigO exactly? O(nlogn)?

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)):

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.